# Multiselect from Ax 2012 Listpage (EP) to downloadDocument.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal

I have been struggling with this for a while now and can't seem to find a solution for my problem. I would really like some help here if possible, it would mean a great deal to me.

I'm currently running a **listpage from ax 2012 on a Enterprise portal** site that allows users to select an invoice and then click a button that starts downloading a generated PDF of the invoice.
It looks like this:
[image]

The button `EpDocuGetMenuitem` (output menu item) refers to a URL webMenuItem that starts the static file `downloadDocument.aspx`.

`downloadDocument.aspx` gets the Websession and axaptasession and extracts a single record that was selected in the Ax `ListPage`.
`downloadDocument.aspx` has the following code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Trace="false" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Portal, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, Custom=null" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Data.Ax, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, Custom=null" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, Custom=null" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Proxy, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, Custom=null" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Metadata.AX, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, Custom=null" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Portal" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Portal.UI" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Portal.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Proxy" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Session" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Adapter" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services.Client" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dynamics" TagName="EPSecurityControl" src="EPSecurityControl.ascx" %>
<dynamics:EPSecurityControl ID="AxEPSecurity" runat="server" /> 
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AxSharepointWebSession session = null;
        try
        {
            session = SessionHelper.Instance.GetSharepointSession();

            if (session != null)
            {
                using (EPDocuGet doc = new EPDocuGet(session.AxaptaAdapter))
                {
                    // EPDocuGet writes directly to the output stream
                    AxQueryString query = new AxQueryString(this.Request);
                    if (query.RecordContext != null)
                    {
                        AxTableContext tableContext = AxTableContext.Create(session, query);
                        if(tableContext != null && tableContext.DataKey != null)
                        {
                            using (IAxaptaRecordAdapter record = tableContext.DataKey.GetRecords(session))
                            {
                                if (tableContext.TableId == TableMetadata.TableNum("DocuRef"))
                                {
                                    doc.runDownload(record);

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Run a report using the Client SDK UserImpersonationContext to revert the credentials from EP application pool to the authenticated user
                                    using (new UserImpersonationContext())
                                    {
                                        doc.runDownload(record);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            // Current design is to not display errors to the user

            // Errors are stored in the event log for review by the site operator
        }
        finally
        {
            if (session != null)
            {
                SessionHelper.Instance.ReleaseSharepointSession(session);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and the interesting part of the file is this code:

```
using (EPDocuGet doc = new EPDocuGet(session.AxaptaAdapter))
{
    // EPDocuGet writes directly to the output stream
    AxQueryString query = new AxQueryString(this.Request);
    if (query.RecordContext != null)
    {
        AxTableContext tableContext = AxTableContext.Create(session, query);
        if (tableContext != null && tableContext.DataKey != null)
        {
             using (IAxaptaRecordAdapter record = tableContext.DataKey.GetRecord(session))
             {
                 if (tableContext.TableId == TableMetadata.TableNum("DocuRef"))
                 {
                       doc.runDownload(record);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      // Run a report using the Client SDK UserImpersonationContext to revert the credentials from EP application pool to the authenticated user
                      using (new UserImpersonationContext())
                      {
                           doc.runDownload(record);
                      }
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The goal here is to get all the selected records accessible in `downloadDocument.aspx`. I have enabled multi select in Ax so I guess it should be possible to get all the records somehow.
I assume this snippet should be different somehow

```
IAxaptaRecordAdapter record = tableContext.DataKey.GetRecord(session)
```

But I can't figure it out.

If I can get all the records in the `downloadDocument.aspx` file I could send a string back to ax to create the necessary documents and send them to the user.

Any suggestions on how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement some time ago.Try using this snippet.
Note that this calls the ax method for each marked line.There might be a more efficient way to send the dataSet as a whole.

```
 IReadOnlySet<DataSetViewRow> rows     = this.ds_yourDSName.GetDataSourceView("YourDSName").DataSetView.GetMarkedRowsSet();
 IEnumerator<DataSetViewRow> enumRows  = rows.GetEnumerator(); 


        while (enumRows.MoveNext())
        {
            //code to get fields needed
            //call to a static ax method to send the fields as parms
            this.AxSession.AxaptaAdapter.CallStaticClassMethod("ClasName","MethodName", parm1, parm2);
        }

        DialogHelper.Close(CloseDialogBehavior.RefreshDataSource);
```